# Launching Activity from Widget passing configuration data

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I am launching an `Activity` from a home screen `Widget`. When doing this I want to pass configuration data from the `Widget` to the `Activity`. So I added extra data to the `Intent`, which works fine. The problem comes when I add more than one `Widget` with different configurations. Regardless of which of the `Widgets` I tap, I always get the configuration of the `Widget` "instance" that was last added. Below is some test code I did to test this, only passing the `appWidgetId` to the `Activity`. The `Activity` should display the `appWidgetId` of the `Widget` that was tapped.

```
public class TestWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,    int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
    }

    private void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, "Id "+appWidgetId);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);       

        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.text_view, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
    }
}
```

and the `Activity` is simply

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.app_text_view);
        textView.setText("appWidgetId " + getIntent().getIntExtra("appWidgetId", -1));
    }
}
```

In the `Intent` I use the flag `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, and there is no science behind this. First I had this as 0, but the flag seem to change the behavior. Without the flag I get the `ID` of a previous `Widget`, with the flag I get the `ID` of the last added (I think).

From the code it is quite obvious that this will not work. The method `setOnCkickPendingIntent` is just called several times without specifying which `Widget` instance (`appWidgetId`) that it refers to.

Is there a way to do this so that the application can get configuration data from the `Widget`? At least it should see the `appWidgetId` of the widget that has been tapped.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The question title of the duplicate is different, but the source of the problem here is that all PendingIntents use the same Intent as well as *the same request code*. So they *are* the same Pending Intent.

Comment: Tanks! I just set the appWidgetId as requestCode in the PendingIntent and it solved it.